# Crashes and visual distortions

Tags: windows-8, sli

Ok so I have two NVidia 760's sli'd up. I'm running windows 8 with the latest drivers and updates.

If I enable sli and use the desktop, I funky distrbances visually inside of windows and random system freezes(becomes completely unresponsive. Also I don't notice any issues/crashes in games). If I disable sli, everything works fine.

Is this a known issue, or is there maybe some other work around besides disabling/enabling sli every time?

If it's not the graphics card could it be caused by something else? Maybe the graphics cards being under powered?

**Power Supply: Corsair 750m**(This was here the whole time...)

Processor: amd 9590

Graphics Cards: 2x nvidia 760

Motherboard: asus crosshair v formula-z

Ram: 4x GSkill f3-12800cl9q-16gbrl 4gb each

I also can't find any useful information in the event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those GPU's will need 170 Watts of power.  With just one a 500W power supply should be enough, but when you run them in SLI you would need a 650W PSU or better.  You can find your PSU's wattage on the side of the hardware or sometimes in the system information.  If that is not the problem then you could try to rollback the GPU's drivers since a new update could have some problems that a previous one does did not, you just never know.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, it seems rolling back the driver solved my issues.